# Spring MVC - @Controller annotation and processing concurrent requests

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using pieces of the Spring MVC framework; in particular, I am making use of the @Controller, @RequestMapping and @ResponseBody annotations, in conjunction with a webstatsHttpMessageConverter hooked up to an OXM jaxb2 marshaller bean. My controller methods use the @RequestParam annotations to parse some GET parameters, query a service that uses a JPA EntityManager behind the scenes, and returns a JAXB object that is converted to its XML representation by the HttpMessageConverter.

I pared this scenario down to a very simple test case to try and determine the location of an execution delay that I have noticed; Example controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping("/my_service__method_endpoint")
    @ResponseBody
 public Jaxb2CompiledClass getSomeData(@RequestParam String param1,
                         @RequestParam Date start, @RequestParam Date end) {
            log.debug("Entering getSomeData");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            log.debug("Finished waiting, leaving getSomeData);

  return new Jaxb2CompiledClass();
 }
```

This scenario works fine, and returns the appropriate data in the appropriate format. However, while load testing this configuration, I've run into a problem - each of my controller methods annotated with @RequestMapping will not run concurrently; if I spawn multiple HTTP requests to the service endpoint, each method call will finish before the next HTTP request is processed. In my actual code, I am using service objects to pull results via JPA and transform those results into an object of the appropriate Jaxb2 class. My understanding is that this controller should be able to run these methods concurrently, one for each HTTP request invoking the /my_service__method_endpoint. Is there some fundamental concept I am missing out on here? The log output from the code above shows that each call to getSomeData is waiting for the previous invocation to complete running before kicking off. This is obviously highly undesirable in a high-volume environment.

Comment: How are you generating the HTTP requests? Using an automated test, or a browser?  Also, can we see the minimal Spring config, to see how everything's wired up?

Comment: At the moment, I am simply generating the multiple HTTP requests in a browser. I have automated test cases that perform requests as well, but they are not concurrent - they exist simply for validating that the XML being generated is correct. I'll get the Spring config posted as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Browsers have built-in logic to throttle concurrent requests, they are a very poor tool for doing this sort of thing. You need to reproduce the load test using an automated tool.

Comment: @skaffman: Yup, now I feel like an idiot. This will teach me to be too lazy to fire up a JMeter test plan. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Skaffman's response is correct - everything is working fine concurrently, but because I was too lazy to use a real load testing tool, my browser was throttling the requests before they were sent.